# How to use numpy for large sets of data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, bigdata, numpy-ndarray, fftw

I have a really big set of datapoints (1 million at least). I am using pyFFTW to do the FFT. To get the x axis values, I am using 
`x = np.linespace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), len(fft_data))`

I need to return all the FFT values as list of lists (e.g: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]`).

I am using this code:

```
for i, item in enumerate(x):
    result.append([item, 2.0 / N * abs(fft_data[i])])
```

The problem is that my for loop has to iterate 500 000 elements and it is not as fast as I want. It takes about 13s on my computer. Is there any way to do this faster? I am thinking to use numpy, but I don't have too much experience with it.

One improvement that I was able to use was to check if `2.0 / N * abs(fft_data[i])` is lower than 0.001. I don't need to return the values that are too small because they are irrelevant for my application.

Do you have any idea how I can speed up the algorithm?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: Im not sure how pyfftw plays a role in here, but your for loop is easily vectorizable. just do `2/N * np.abs(fft_data)` to get your `y` column, and use your `x` that you already have to just concanenate (through `np.concatenate` or `hstack`) your `y` and `x`. Shouldn't take longer than 1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, just

```
y = 2.0 / N * np.abs(fft_data)
```

and `hstack`

```
np.hstack([x.reshape(-1,1),
           y.reshape(-1,1)])
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Is there any way not to remove from this array the lists that have y less than 0.001?

Comment: For the filtering I used `result[result:, 1] > 0.001]`

Answer (score 1):

Vectorize!

`result = np.array([x, np.abs(fft_data) * 2.0/N])`